# Watchkit Interface Controller 38mm and 42mm background image size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard, watchkit, apple-watch

For some reason, I have searched high and low, and cannot find the exact image sizes that I need to supply for a background image for both the `38mm` and `42mm` sizes in `Watchkit`. Currently I am stretching a smaller image using "scale to fill".

[image]

[image]

I don't want it stretched, so I am looking for real pixel sizes.

Comment: are you looking for pixel size? Isn't this it? http://www.macrumors.com/2014/11/18/apple-watch-resolutions/

Comment: @Nic Hubbard How the local notification in Watch app look like? Is it same as remote notification? does notification controller interface used for local notification by watch app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code I use to get the size for the background image in my `WKInterfaceController`.  My app has a page control, you you probably don't want the extra -14 at the end.

```
-(CGSize)backgroundSize
{
    CGRect contentFrame = self.contentFrame;
    CGSize size = contentFrame.size;
    CGFloat contentScale = 2.0;
    size.width *= contentScale;
    size.height *= contentScale;

    //I lined up the generated image with one in the simulator until
    //they perfectly matched.  I did this on both 38 and 42 mm.
    //I am not sure why they all came out to be off 4.

    //There is an offset of 10 in IB and I am not sure I need this
    //to be 4 to match perfect.
    size.height -= 4;

    //it looks like there is 2 pixels around the edge
    size.width -= 4;

    //Using page mode we need to take off an additional 14 pixels for the page dots at the bottom
    size.height -= 14;

    return size;
}
```

Comment: Or better yet, does Watchkit allow me to draw a native gradient using `CAGradientLayer`?

Comment: To draw a gradient you will need to draw it to an image and then set it as the background image on a group.  You can only access the limited interface elements as described here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WatchKit_framework/index.html.  You can draw a CGGradient to a bitmap context.

Comment: The 2 pixels on the side can be disabled by selection the Interface Controller > Insets > Custom > Change Left / Right from 1 to 0

Comment: @StephenJohnson How the local notification in Watch app look like? Is it same as remote notification? does notification controller interface used for local notification by watch app?

Comment: @StephenJohnson how to get frame if we dont have the page view?

Comment: @iOSdev this only works from a `WKInterfaceController` subclass since it calls `contentFrame`.

Comment: if there is a  WKInterfaceGroup before the image how can we get the image  pixel by taking off the group and status bar?